# Dismiss a system dialog on BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, dialog, integration

I have a BlackBerry app running in the background that needs to know when a "Missed call" system dialog is brought up by the system, and programmatically close it without user intervention. How can I do that?

I could actually *almost* know when the dialog is brought up, i.e. a little later I programmatically end the call...but how can I get a reference to the dialog, and close it?

Comment: Do you have access to UiEngine or UiApplication instances from your application? IE, does it extend UiApplication or communicate with a foreground app that can reference a UiApplication?

Comment: yes I can reference UiApplication.
But, if possible, I'd like a solution that works in both cases...just in case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Key press injection for device *Close* button looks like this:

```
KeyEvent inject = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.KEY_DOWN, Characters.ESCAPE, 0);
inject.post();
```

Don't forget to set permissions for device release:
Options => Advanced Options => Applications => [Your Application] =>Edit Default permissions =>Interactions =>key stroke Injection

May be useful:
[BlackBerry - Simulate a KeyPress event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292896/blackberry-simulate-a-keypress-event/1298900#1298900)

Code sample:

```
class Scr extends MainScreen implements PhoneListener {
    public Scr() {
        Phone.addPhoneListener(this);
    }

    public boolean onClose() {
        Phone.removePhoneListener(this);
        return super.onClose();
    }

    public void callDisconnected(int callId) {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){public void run() {
            KeyEvent event = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.KEY_DOWN,  
                        Characters.ESCAPE, 
                        KeyListener.STATUS_NOT_FROM_KEYPAD);
            event.post();
        }}, 1000);      
    }

    public void callAdded(int callId) {
    }

    public void callAnswered(int callId) {
    }

    public void callConferenceCallEstablished(int callId) {
    }

    public void callConnected(int callId) {
    }

    public void callDirectConnectConnected(int callId) {    
    }

    public void callDirectConnectDisconnected(int callId) {
    }

    public void callEndedByUser(int callId) {
    }

    public void callFailed(int callId, int reason) {
    }

    public void callHeld(int callId) {
    }

    public void callIncoming(int callId) {
    }

    public void callInitiated(int callid) {
    }

    public void callRemoved(int callId) {
    }

    public void callResumed(int callId) {   
    }

    public void callWaiting(int callid) {
    }

    public void conferenceCallDisconnected(int callId) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the dialog is there, and is the topmost dialog, the EventInjector APIs might do it - net.rim.device.api.system.EventInjector.  When you know the dialog is there, send a KeyEvent with an ESCAPE keycode.  That API is usually locked out in most enterprise environments though...

Disclaimer: I haven't tried it myself, I'd be a little surprised if it worked, since that might mean you could also dismiss the 'Allow This Connection' dialog, which would be a security hole.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable(){
  public void run(){
    UiApplication.getActiveScreen().close();
  }
});
```