# Intercept outgoing call in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, integration, call, intercept, background-application

we are looking for a way to do the following:

- user with BB enters a number (or selects a contact and clicks 'send')
- our app in the background detects the call event
- our app does something (e.g. blocks the call / makes a call to a different number, etc)

can this be done at all? can it be done transparently to the user (i.e. no dialogs or user involvement)? 
which APIs should I look at?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

### Outgoing call interception

[call interception http://img200.imageshack.us/img200/6927/callinit.png](http://img200.imageshack.us/img200/6927/callinit.png)

- create extention of [Application](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Application.html) for background service
- implement [PhoneListener](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/phone/PhoneListener.html)
- use [callInitiated](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/phone/PhoneListener.html#callInitiated(int))
- should be [signed](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/javaappdev/codekeys.jsp) before use on device
- should be tested against [known issue](http://rim.lithium.com/rim/board/message?message.uid=185907#U185907)

Code example:

```
import net.rim.blackberry.api.phone.Phone;
import net.rim.blackberry.api.phone.PhoneListener;
import net.rim.device.api.system.Application;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.Dialog;

public class CatchCall extends Application implements PhoneListener {
    public CatchCall() {
        Phone.addPhoneListener(this);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CatchCall().enterEventDispatcher();
    }
    public void callAdded(int callId) {
    }
    public void callAnswered(int callId) {
    }
    public void callConferenceCallEstablished(int callId) {
    }
    public void callConnected(int callId) {
    }
    public void callDirectConnectConnected(int callId) {
    }
    public void callDirectConnectDisconnected(int callId) {
    }
    public void callDisconnected(int callId) {
    }
    public void callEndedByUser(int callId) {
    }
    public void callFailed(int callId, int reason) {
    }
    public void callHeld(int callId) {
    }
    public void callIncoming(int callId) {
    }
    public void callInitiated(int callid) {
        Dialog.inform("call initiated");
    }
    public void callRemoved(int callId) {
    }
    public void callResumed(int callId) {
    }
    public void callWaiting(int callid) {
    }
    public void conferenceCallDisconnected(int callId) {
    }
}
```

### Cancel call

You can use event injection to fire Close button press event:

```
public void dropCall()
{
    KeyEvent inject = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.KEY_DOWN, Characters.ESCAPE, 0);
    inject.post();
}
```

Don't forget to set permissions for device release: Options => Advanced Options => Applications => [Your Application] =>Edit Default permissions =>Interactions =>key stroke Injection

See also
[BlackBerry - Simulate a KeyPress event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292896/blackberry-simulate-a-keypress-event)

Comment: thanks - that's great!
Do you know if there is a way to drop the call after catching the event?